# Optional parameter and Symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, paperclip

I'm trying to pass a symbol as an optional parameter but I've got this error

> syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end

Here's my code :

project.rb

```
    def homepage_image_url(options = {})
      url = self.homepage_image.url.blank? ? Project::current_setting.default_project_image(options) : self.homepage_image.url(options)
    end
```

projects_helper.rb

```
  def homepage_image_for(project_id, size)
    format = size.to_sym
    project = Project.find(project_id)
    image_tag project.homepage_image_url(format) :alt => html_escape(project.name)
  end
```

And the extract of my view _project.html.haml

```
= homepage_image_for(project.id, thumbnail)
```

My default_url for Paperclip is : `https://something_here/default_project_:style.png`
and three styles are defined, "thumbnail" is one of them.

I need to pass a symbol in order to get the size of the image I want to display, all of this using Paperclip. I'm not familiar with optionals parameters so maybe that's where the problem is.
Thanks in advance, Rob.

EDIT : Sorry for the missing "?", mistake in my copy/paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ternary operator expects a `?`

```
self.homepage_image.url.blank? ? "something" : "something else"
```

Also, there is a syntax error in this line

```
image_tag project.homepage_image_url(format) :alt => html_escape(project.name)
```

It should be

```
image_tag project.homepage_image_url(format, :alt => html_escape(project.name))
```